# Extract vectors from elements of list of vectors

Tags: r

I have some json data `[{a:10, b:123,c:4.5},{a:2,b:5,c:33}]` and so on that I read into R via `json_data <- fromJSON(paste(json_file, collapse=""))` (json_file is the input url). So far so fine.
Now I would like to create vectors from this input which `fromJSON` has converted into a List of vectors where the vectors have components a,b,c.

Is there a better way than looping over the input list and doing this manually by concatenating the individual vector components on the new target vector(s)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a list like this:

```
l <- list(c(a=10, b=123, c=4.5),c(a=2,b=5,c=33))
```

You could just do something like the following:

```
df <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, l))
#    a   b    c
# 1 10 123  4.5
# 2  2   5 33.0
as.list(df)
# $a
# [1] 10  2
# $b
# [1] 123   5
# $c
# [1]  4.5 33.0
```

(The `do.call(rbind, X)` construct is handy, allowing you to `rbind` together the elements of a list of arbitrary length. You can then slice and dice the resulting matrix as you see fit --- I just converted it to a `data.frame` and then to a `list` to show a couple of possibilities.)

Comment: Very glad to hear it. It's nice when a simple solution works so well.